# Multisite Related Posts

Tags: wordpress

I have currently been using this code to output related posts for each of my blog posts based on the tags associated with that post.

```
<?php

    $orig_post = $post;

    global $post;

    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

    if ($tags) {

    $tag_ids = array();

    foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;

    $args=array(
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
         );

    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="brelated">
        <?php get_the_image(array(
    'custom_key' => array('post_thumbnail','thumbnail'),
    'default_size' => 'thumbnail',
    'default_image' => $defthumb,
    'image_scan' => true,
    'image_class' => 'single',
)); ?>
<a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
    <? }
       }
       }
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
```

However, I would like to include related posts from another blog on my multisite intall based on those tags.

Is there any way that I can use similar code to achieve this using the switch_to_blog() function. So far I have had very little success. I am not a programmer, but I do have a very good understanding of how WordPress code works.